# sngrl sphinx search can't understand how it works

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sphinx

I am using Laravel 5.3 and i was trying to use sngrl sphinx, following this git : https://github.com/sngrl/sphinxsearch.

I followed all the installation and configuration steps, but in the end when i try to use, i got always return null ( the answer is false).

This is the configuration:

```
<?php
return array(
    'host'    => '127.0.0.1',
    'port'    => 3306,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'indexes' => array(
        'my_index_name' => array('table' => 'users', 'column' => 'email'),
    ),
    'mysql_server' => array(
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => 3306
    )
);
```

,
And this is where i am trying to do the query :

```
public function teste(Request $request)
{
    $sphinx = new SphinxSearch();
    $results = $sphinx->search('daniel@gmail.com', 'users_index');

    dd($results);

    return back();
}
```

or something like this to select all

```
 public function teste(Request $request)
    {
        $sphinx = new SphinxSearch();
        $results = $sphinx->search('', 'users_index');

        dd($results);

        return back();
    }
```

The result is this : http://prntscr.com/ec33mr

I belive that i could be missing something but i don't know.

I searched  about it, but i can't find mutch information about it,
if anyone can help me plz.

António Gonçalves

Comment: *Do you definitly have a searchd daemon running on the server, and listening on port **3306** ?* (Also note that port 3306 normally used for mysql server, so if have searchd API running there instead, that seems kinda confusing) pt 9312 is more commonly used for SphinxAPI Protocol.

Comment: i don't have searchd daemon running becouse i didn't know if i have to. I only followed the guide i linked. But you mean, i need to have an api running to use this Sphinx. I think i will try then

Comment: YEs, you need a server running (and with it some indexes for it search!). The server is the part that actually 'answers' the query. The PHP class is just a convenient **wrapper**, that forwards queries to Sphinx server. Guess that article assumes you *already* have a functioning server!

Comment: With your help i could put it running. Now i am exploring it trying to get full extension of it

Answer (score 0):

```
public function teste(Request $request)
{
    $sphinx = new SphinxSearch();
    $results = $sphinx->search('', 'users_index')->get();

    dd($results);

    return back();
}
```

Please try this, 
Reference : 
https://github.com/sngrl/sphinxsearch#usage

Comment: i have linked the same link you did at the begining of my post. I think i have my connection ok, but i don't know if the way i am trying to do the query is the correct one.

Comment: On the line where you get the results, do ->get() . You're doing the  $sphinx->search('', 'users_index') but missing the ->get()

Comment: Yes i know... but when i do $result->get(), the result is false. This return means that it couldn't find anything, or have some error. I tryied to check erros, but the answer was "", and empty value, so i assumed that i had no errors, but still can't find values

Comment: and with ->query() instead of ->get()

Comment: I keep having the same answer : False. Using >query() or >get()